# Designing a mergable data format

Tags: merge, data-driven

When making data driven applications in large groups of collaborators comprised of different disciplines (eg. when making games), we often have to decide what format we are going to store that data in.

XML is notorious in it's inability to merge, which makes practical workflows that include branches a lot more painful.  People even write CS theses about the topic for their degrees: https://curve.carleton.ca/system/files/etd/c6fe573c-50e5-4439-9963-be75ed60547b/etd_pdf/27e1a5dbb0c326bedf15ff286310222a/wei-mergingofxmldocuments.pdf

JSON merges better, but is still not really merge friendly.

Does anyone know if there are any formats that merge well, or if designing a custom data format, what it might look like to aid mergability?

I'm only concerned with how it affects mergability.

Data size and runtime considerations are not a concern due to the fact that the format that the content creators save their files in does not have to be the same format that the application uses at runtime - it can be transformed to a runtime friendly representation.

I'm also not concerned with human editability / readability, because a human friendly, performant, editor can be made to let people work with the data.

Comment: What is your definition of "merge friendly"? Have you considered Google protobuf? It is not "user editable, but I think there are tools that make it "user editable" for all practical purposes. (besides this it has TONS of other benefits like performance and size etc).

Comment: By merge friendly I mean in the context of source control.  One way this comes up is if I'm in a feature branch working on something, and then want to merge it back into trunk/head/whatever, but there are changes to the file in that branch as well, then there's a potential merge conflict.  


I haven't thought about using protobuf for this.  Do you think it'd be applicable?

Comment: Answer I think  is no, not applicable :). The protobuf data format is binary so the data is not very mergeable which is what you need. But the protobuf protocol definition language is text based and will most likely be very merge-able in that sense.